# Rust "Not all control paths return a value" in expression

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
//returns GREATER if x is greater than y
//LESS if x is less than y
//EQUAL if x == y
fn less_or_greater(x: int, y: int) -> &str{
    let result = 
        if x == y {
            "EQUAL"
        }
        else if x > y{
            "GREATER"
        }
        else {
            "LESS"
        }; 
    return result;
}
```

How do I return from this function using the recommended Rust style of not including the return statement?  If I don't include it I get the following compile error:

```
test.rc:29:0: 1:0 error: not all control paths return a value
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I think this problem is due to my lack of understanding about ";" in Rust and the difference between Expressions and Statements.  Thanks!

Comment: I hope this was a toy example and you're not actually using strings like this instead of enums. `std::cmp::Ordering` is an enum with variants `Less`, `Equal` and `Greater` and is used as the return type of the `TotalOrd.cmp` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last statement in a block acts as its return value, so you can just do

```
fn less_or_greater(x: int, y: int) -> &'static str {
    if x == y {
        "EQUAL"
    } else if x > y {
        "GREATER"
    } else {
        "LESS"
    }
}
```

Comment: So long as you leave off the semicolon at the end of the statement.  I guess not doing that introduces a new, empty statement, with no/unit value.